# Rails model definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What does the following model definition (lines 2-4) mean in rails?
What is`:members` symbol denote here? I don't find it used elsewhere.
I am new to rails and trying to work on a project.

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :members,
:join_table => 'membership',
:class_name => 'User'
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has_and_belongs_to_many line sets up a HABTM relationship between the UserGroup model and the User model.  The name of the association is 'members' and it is stored in the "membership" table.

This means you if you have an instance `g` of the UserGroup model, you can do `g.members` and get back all of the Users that are linked to `g` in the `membership` table.

Read through this page for more information:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_and_belongs_to_many-association-reference

Comment: Is this what translates to `create_table "memberships"` in schema.rb?

Comment: yes, but the schema isn't what creates the table, it's a record of your database structure (as typically created by `migrations` in the app/db/migrate folder). Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#what-are-schema-files-for